# Does anything special happen if I transfer a Pokémon from RSE to ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire, pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I've recently come across two fanmade comics which depict the player character of Pokémon Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald trading one of their Pokémon to FireRed/LeafGreen, then transferring it to Diamond/Pearl/Platinum, which is then traded to HeartGold/SoulSilver, Black/White, Black2/White2, X/Y, and finally back to OmegaRuby/AlphaSapphire.

When this happens, we get a heartwarming scene with the Pokémon being reunited with his original trainer.

Watching those comics made me wonder if anything special would happen if a Pokémon were transferred all the way from RSE to ORAS. Since I never owned any 3rd-gen game, I can't verify this for myself.

---

Here are the two comics:

[May & Jirachi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq8eA.jpg)
[Brendan & Delcatty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgKmS.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Serebii and [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/2n0jbl/you_do_get_something_for_having_a_rse_pokemon/), You DO get something for having a RSE pokemon travel back with you to ORAS Hoenn, you should get a certificate like this:

[image]

How to obtain it:

> Go to the Cove Lily hotel in Lilicove City, on the second floor you'll see a guy wearing a dinosaur pants walking around a table, he is the director of Gamefreak, talk to him and show him a pokemon from R/S/E... and there you go.

Source: [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/792673-pokemon-omega-ruby/70687110)

Comment: Wow, this is beautiful. It really makes me regret having skipped gen 3.

Comment: Same for me, I've played it only on emulator.